# Why is LockSupport provided by Java but not useful

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking, language-concepts

Strangely, [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html) says:

> These methods are designed to be used as tools for creating
>   higher-level synchronization utilities, and are not in themselves
>   useful for most concurrency control applications.

Is there any example/scenario to illustrate `JavaSupport` is useful?

Comment: Not sure if this shouldn't better go to programmers.stackexchange.com ... in other words: what is the problem that you intend to solve?

Comment: Just emphasizing what Kayaman already said;  `LockSupport` _is_ quite useful, but  most of the clever things you can do with it already been done in open-source libraries. if you find yourself tempted to use `LockSupport`, you should first try to find some higher-level synchronization class that would better fit or simplify your design.  Chances are good that you will find one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's used by many classes in the `java.util.concurrent` package, as explained in the Javadoc. You're not supposed to (or rather you don't need to) use it unless you're creating your own high-level concurrency classes, since there are plenty of ready easy-to-use classes that can accomplish what you want, without going down to the "bare metal".

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any example/scenario to illustrate [`LockSupport`] is useful?

Look through the source code of the Java concurrency classes to find where the class is used:

- These are examples of the kind of scenario where `LockSupport` is useful.
- They probably also illustrate the comment in the javadoc that you quoted.  These primitives are low-level, and difficult to use directly.

To get you started, `LockSupport` is used in the following classes in the standard class libraries (Java 8):

- java.util.concurrent.Exchanger
- java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
- java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue
- java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
- java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock
- java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer
- java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedLongSynchronizer
- java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue
- java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool
- java.util.concurrent.Phaser